# How to get the values from a groovy output in jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy

My one output from jenkins groovy script is :

```
{
  "Code" : "Success",
  "LastUpdated" : "2021-08-31T18:12:23Z",
  "Type" : "sample",
  "AccessKeyId" : "reallysample",
  "SecretAccessKey" : "valuesomerandom",
  "Token" : "hugewrong+data=",
  "Expiration" : "2021-09-01T00:48:09Z"
}
```

How can I extratc the values for  - AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey from this. Please help, currently I am blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `readJSON` keyword which is part of the [Pipeline Utility Steps](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) Jenkins plugin.

> Reads a file in the current working directory or a String as a plain text JSON file. The returned object is a normal Map with String keys or a List of primitives or Map.

So you can use the `readJSON` to convert your JSON output into a dictionary that will allow easy access to all variables.
Here is an example (assuming you output is inside the `output` variable):

```groovy
def props = readJSON text: output // assuming output contains your JSON text

println "AccessKeyId is: ${props.AccessKeyId}"  // you can also use props['AccessKeyId']
println "SecretAccessKey is: ${props.SecretAccessKey}"
```